# If $x^{T}A^{T}Ax = x^Tx$ holds for every $x$, then $A^{T} A = I_n$

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

> Given $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, if $$\left( \forall x \in\mathbb R^n \right) \left(x^{T} A^{T} A x = x^T x \right)$$ how to conclude that $A^{T}A = I_n$?

---

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I think if there exists at least one $y$ such that $y^TA^TAy \neq y^Ty$, then $A^T A$ can't be the identity matrix. If must hold for all $x$, in that case the proof is easy.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes I agree with the edits, but why we have to show it to be 0?

Comment: Trust me. Just do it. Then note that the skew-symmetric part of a matrix contributes nothing to a quadratic form.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Got it, thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the underlying field is real. It suffices to prove the stronger statement that if $S$ is a symmetric matrix and $x^TSx$ is identically zero, then $S=0$. To prove this, put $x=v+Sv$ for some arbitrary vector $v$.

Comment: I think I kinda understand what you're saying, do you mean that since x is non zero, therefore the only solution is S = 0?

Comment: @busyyyy No. The point is to show that $Sv=0$ for all $v$. That's what $S=0$ means.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach (in the final stage of proof).
We have $$\left( \forall x \in\mathbb R^n \right) \left(x^{T} (A^{T} A -I) x =0 \right)$$

$S=A^{T} A -I$ is obviously symmetric hence it is diagonalizable.

Equation above must be hold also for any eigenvector $v$ of $S$.
i.e. $v^TSv=0 =v^T\lambda v$,
hence every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $S$ is zero and it's diagonal form must be zero matrix what means $S$ is zero matrix itself.