# show that that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ if $\|Ax\|_2=\|x\|_2$ then $A$ is an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

1. Show that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
   if $\langle Ax,x\rangle=x^TAx=0$ then $A=0$
2. By the help of $(1)$ show that that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ if $\|Ax\|_2=\|x\|_2$ then $A$ is an orthogonal matrix

---

What I have tried so far:

For $(1)$ I have shown that
$$x^TAx=x^TA_+x=0$$
$$A_+=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$$
since it holds for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we can write
$$0=(x+y)^TA(x+y)=x^TAx+x^TAy+y^TAx+y^TAy=x^TAy+y^TAx=x^T(A+A^T)y
$$
Then I use spectral theorem which states that for every real symmetric matrix $A$ there exists orthogonal matrix $P$ such that
$$D=PAP^T \implies A=P^TDP $$
Now using this fact I can write, considering $y=Px$
$$x^TA_+x=x^TP^TDPx=(Px)^TD(Px)=y^TDy=0$$
I have come so far. Now my question is this enough for proving $A=0$? Or there are more steps to make it clear?

---

For $(2)$

I honestly don't exactly know how to use $(1)$ to prove this one however here is what I have tried
$$<Ax,Ax>=\|x\|_2^2 \implies <x,A^TAx>=\|x\|_2^2$$

We know for norm-$2$ if $P$ is orthogonal $\|x\|_2=\|Px\|_2$ so
$$<Ax,Ax>=\|Px\|_2^2 \implies <x,A^TAx>=<x,P^TPx>$$
Is this enough for proving $P=A$, I guess not and that's exactly my question.

Comment: wait, $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: @Exodd No $A$ is NOT symmetric. It is $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: You used the Spectral theorem, for which you need $A$ symmetric

Comment: @Exodd I fixed it, typo, I used spectral theorem for $A_+$

Comment: I think you rather mean: "Show that if for every $x\in\Bbb R^n$ we have $\langle x,Ax\rangle=0$, then $A=0$" etc. -- There's a huge difference between $\forall x\colon (P\to Q)$ and $(\forall x\colon P)\to Q$

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for inner product brackets, not `<` and `>`. You can see the difference here: $\langle x, y\rangle$ vs $<x, y>$.

Comment: $\langle Ax,x\rangle =\langle x,Ax\rangle$ for real matrices. @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050968/if-xtatax-xtx-holds-for-every-x-then-at-a-i-n

Comment: also useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3991250/characterization-of-an-antisymmetric-matrix  as you see in 1) $A$   is not necessary zero matrix, it can be skew-symmetric one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything done so far seems too complicated.

**Assume $A$ is symmetric.** Start with $e_i^\intercal A e_i = 0$ implies $a_{ii} = 0.$ Next, $(e_i + e_j)^\intercal A (e_i + e_j) = a_{ii} + a_{ij} + a_{ji} + a_{jj} = a_{ij} + a_{ji}.$ This implies $A$ is also antisymmetric, so $A^\intercal = A = -A$ and $A = 0.$

**What to do if $A$ is not symmetric?** I think the result of part 1 is false (part 2 *still is true*). We will still reach that $a_{ij} + a_{ji} = 0,$ so $A$ must be *antisymmetric.* Consider then $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &-1 \\ 1 &0 \end{bmatrix}.$ Then, $(x, y) A (x, y)^\intercal = (x, y) (-y, x)^\intercal = 0.$ And $A$ is *not* the matrix zero.

**Lemma.** Any linear function that preserves norm in $\mathbf{R}^d$ is an orthogonal transformation.
*Proof* Let $A$ be such linear function, that is $\| A x\| = \|x\|.$ We may use *polarization identity*
$$
4(x, y) = \|x + y\|^2 - \|x - y\|^2.
$$
In the right hand side we can add $A,$ and by linearity we reach $(Ax, Ay) = (x, y)$ for all vectors $x, y.$ Then $(x, y) = (Ax, Ay) = (x, A^\intercal A y)$ (this is true actually whether or not $A$ is symmetric). So that $(x, (A^\intercal A - I)y) = 0$ for all $x, y$ and now we may apply the first part to the symmetric matrix $A^\intercal A - I$ to reach the conclusion. QED