# Is the "Its transpose is its inverse" definition of an orthogonal matrix equivalent to the "It preserves the dot product" definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

A long time ago, I was taught that a real $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is called orthogonal if $AA^t=I$. But recently I learned from a DG book that $A$ is said to be orthogonal if it preserves the dot product:
$$(Ax)\cdot(Ay)=x\cdot y\quad\text{for all }x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
Are these two definitions equivalent? It is easy to see that the former implies the latter:
$$(Ax)\cdot(Ay)=(Ay)^t(Ax)=(y^t A^t)(Ax)=y^t x=x\cdot y$$
But I have a hard time going from the latter to the former. Is it possible? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is $(Ae_{i})\cdot (Ae_{j})$ the $(i,j)$-entry of $A^t A$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050968/if-xtatax-xtx-holds-for-every-x-then-at-a-i-n/4051379#4051379

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $Ax\cdot Ay=x\cdot y$ for all $y$.

Recall that  $Ax\cdot Ay=A^{T}Ax\cdot y$.

So $(A^{T}Ax-x)\cdot y=0$.

Put $y=A^{T}Ax-x$ to see that $A^{T}Ax=x \ \forall x$.

Comment: Should that last line be $y = A^TAx - x$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that if
$$
(Ax)\cdot (Ay)=x\cdot y$$
for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then
$$ (x)\cdot(A^tAy)=x\cdot y.$$
Using bilinearity of the dot product, we have
$$(x)\cdot ([A^tA-I]y)=0. $$
By non-degeneracy of the dot product, there holds
$$(A^tA-I)y=0, \;\;\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n. $$
Therefore
$$ A^tA=I,$$
and we are done.